# Generate application Installer with MS VS Installer Projects from command line

Tags: installation

I created an installer for my C# .Net named "MyApplication" using the "Visual Studio Installer Projects" plugin (version Visual Studio 2022 Pro). When I generate the installer directly from the Visual Studio IDE it is generated properly, the .MSI is created and works without problems ( I simply press right button over the installer project in the VS Solution Explorer and then Build ).

I need to automate the operation so I need to generate the installer from command line, but I can't, It always get an error from "devenv". To do it I open a CMD console from Visual Studio and then try to execute different commands to execute the installer generator but I always get an error indicating something like "Unable to complete the operation. The parameter is not correct." followed by all the devenv help information, but no more details. I don't know what I am doing wrong. In fact I can compile MyApplication from the command line with devenv, but I can't generate the installer.

Maybe anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong. It would also be usefull to get more information from the devenv execution to try to find the error.

These are some examples of the commands I executed from VS commandline in the MyInstaller.vdproj folder:

`devenv "../MyApplication/MyApplication.sln" /build Release MyInstaller.vdproj /build Release`

`devenv "../MyApplication/MyApplication.sln" MyInstaller.vdproj /build Release`

My application is compiled without problems if I write:

`devenv "../MyApplication/MyApplication.sln" /build Release`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was compiling from commandline in Release but I hadn't previously enabled MyApplicationInstaller to complie in Release in the Visual Studio "Configs administration" ( I only had it enabled for compiling in Debug ).

So I finally solved that issue by proprely adjusting the build configurations in the "Config administration" options in Visual Studio:
[Config administration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2nF6.png). I enabled all the projects for compiling in Release.

After having changed that I am able to compile the whole solution ( MyApplication and MyApplicationInstaller projects) with this simple command from Visual Studio Command Line:

```
devenv "MyApplication.sln" /build Release
```

That compiles the whole solution ( MyApplication and MyApplicationInstaller projects ), but to only execute the installer type:

```
devenv "MyApplication.sln" /Project "../MyApplicationInstaller/MyApplicationInstaller.vdproj" /build Release
```